# What command in JavaScript would you use to get and put data into a MongoDB database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, http

Would you use the standard $http.get() and $http.put() request, or is there another method of doing this? I am trying to put JSON objects into my database, but I am not certain exactly how to do that with JavaScript.

Comment: How does http factor in here? Are you trying to take JSON (note that [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)) from the *client* and send it to the server to be stored in a DB there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http` is a AngularJS service. Assuming that you're trying to insert a document to a MongoDB collection using Node.js, you could use `db.collection.save([your-object)`.

Reference: [db.collection.save()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/)